# Making many duplicates of columns and renaming them automatically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas in Python.

`import pandas as pd`

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [3,2,1]})
```

I want to make three copies of each column and name the columns as A1 to A4, and B1 to B4. Example of desired output:

```
pd.DataFrame({"A1": [1,2,3], "A2": [1,2,3], "A3": [1,2,3], "A4": [1,2,3], "B1": [3,2,1], "B2": [3,2,1], "B3": [3,2,1], "B4": [3,2,1]})
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` with [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) i.e

```
ndf = pd.concat([df.add_suffix(str(i+1)) for i in range(4)],1)
```

Output :

```
  A1  B1  A2  B2  A3  B3  A4  B4
0   1   3   1   3   1   3   1   3
1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   1   3   1   3   1   3   1
```

For sorted columns use `ndf = ndf.sort_index(1)`

Comment: stolen your string create loop :-)

Comment: But OP output is different ;)

Comment: @ jezreal sort index() ?

Comment: Nice one!! +1 Small modification suggestion: `ndf = pd.concat([df.add_suffix(i) for i in range(1,5)],1)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your dataframe, you can construct the following one:

```
pd.DataFrame({'{}{}'.format(c,i): v for c,v in df.to_dict().items()
                                    for i in range(1,5)})
```

with `df` the original dataframe. This then generates:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'{}{}'.format(c,i): v for c,v in df.to_dict().items()
...                                     for i in range(1,5)})
   A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4
0   1   1   1   1   3   3   3   3
1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   1   1   1   1
```

Or a bit shorter (but a syntax that is by some considered not very safe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'%s%s'%(c,i): v for c,v in df.to_dict().items()
                              for i in range(1,5)})
```

Comment: Nice. What does `{}{}` do?

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.concat([df]*4,1,keys=[str(i+1) for i in range(4)])
df.columns=df.columns.swaplevel().map(''.join)
df
Out[493]: 
   A1  B1  A2  B2  A3  B3  A4  B4
0   1   3   1   3   1   3   1   3
1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   1   3   1   3   1   3   1
```

Comment: But OP output is different ;)

Comment: Column names need to be A1 B1 ... na?

Comment: @jezrael swaplevel:-)

Comment: Swaplevel and sort index sometimes go hand in hand.